# How should I design endpoint to return different models depending on User role in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

So lets assume I have 2 model classes - User and Presentation, and they look something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Presentation {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}

@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
}
```

As you can see I have a unidirectional mapping for user in Presentation class. My endpoint looks something like this:

```
@RestController
public class PresentationController {
    
    @GetMapping("/{presentationId}")
    public PresentationDTO getPresentation(@PathVariable Long presentationId) {
        return presentationService.getPresentationById(presentationId);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<PresentationDTO> getAllPresentations() {
        return presentationService.getAllPresentations();
    }
}
```

Now for my question - how do I change getAllPresentations() to return the presentations that the users with role "user" own, and return all presentations for users with role "admin"? I know I can create a separate endpoint with a different mapping (like /admin/presentations) and add @PreAuthorize(hasRole("admin")), but here is the tricky part.
For the getAllPresentations() endpoint which everyone who is authenticated is supposed to fetch his own presentations, how do I know for which user I have to return his presentations? Maybe I can get the username as a parameter but that might be dangerous cause he can submit any username he wants and get the presentations for that user. I don't know too much about Spring Security and I don't even know the right question to ask google to get an answer so I'm stuck...
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass username to your controller method. The currently authenticated user is available through a number of different mechanisms in Spring.The simplest way to retrieve the currently authenticated principal is via a static call to the `SecurityContextHolder` like this :

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String username = authentication.getName();
```

So you can refactor you method `getAllPresentations()` in service class to accept `username` as argument, and then you can load user by passed `username` and return presentations for that user.

Comment: hvala puno... :D

Comment: Nema na cemu komsija :D

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you want is to use `@PostFilter` annotation to filter `List<Presentation>` that the authenticated user owns or if the authenticated user has a role `ADMIN` like this:

```
@GetMapping
@PostFilter("filterObject.user.username == authentication.principal.username or hasRole('ADMIN')")
public List<PresentationDTO> getAllPresentations() {
    return presentationService.getAllPresentations();
}
```